# Is there a way to get version of Cabal package in source code of the package?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Say I have a console program that has an option to display its
version. Currently whenever I update version in `.cabal` file I need to go
to source code and update constant — string representation of current
version number as well. This feels against DRY principle and now I'm
wondering, is it possible to get version of my project as defined in
`.cabal` file from source code? Maybe Cabal defines some CPP macro or
something else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Indeed Cabal allows to access information from `.cabal` file in your
program. [According to Cabal documentation](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code),
you can import special module that exists during building of your package,
like this:

```
import Paths_packagename (version)
import Data.Version (showVersion)

myVersion :: String
myVersion = showVersion version
```

The module `Paths_packagename` provides `version` of type
[Version](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Version.html).

Comment: Is this still the current best approach?

Comment: What else is the path_packagename exporting? I cannot find any documentation as it is an automatically generated package. I would appreciate a link!

Comment: One small notice: change `<packagename>` to your real package name.  E.g. if your package name is `'my-awesome-package'` you should `import Paths_my_awesome_package`